# Will this memory be compatible with my notebook?

Tags: windows, memory, upgrade

My notebook is an HP dv6757ca which has the following specs:

- Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit (currently using Windows 8 Developer Preview 32-bit)
- Intel Centrino Duo @ 1.6 GHz
- **2 GB RAM**

I am planning to upgrade from 2GB to 3GB and using [Crucial's Memory Tool](http://www.crucial.com) I was able to determine that the following memory was compatible with my machine:

> DDR2 PC2-6400, DDR2 PC2-5300, DDR2 (non-ECC)

I found [this](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/pny-2gb-pc-5300-ddr2-laptop-memory-mn2048sd2-667/10125911.aspx?path=f71a0cbb0a18ca920c0877dd5eb014dben02) with a bit of searching and I was wondering if it would be compatible with my machine. From what I can tell, it *looks* like it will be... but I noticed that the memory tool mentions "PC2" whereas the product specification page mentions "PC".

---

**Edit:** I found the data sheet for my chipset (an Intel PM965 Express Chipset) and it lists the following features:

[image: chpset datasheet]

Will any of these features cause trouble or indicate a possible incompatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no such thing thing as "PC-5300", so that's a misprint.

The "2" in PC2 means DDR2, which the linked RAM is.

Based on the info you've provided, I can't see any reason that won't work. :)

Comment: Is there a tool to determine whether this memory module will work with my existing module? I have 2x 1GB sticks in there now and I would be swapping one of them out for the new 2GB stick.

Comment: I know of no such tool, but there shouldn't be any trouble mixing them, as long as you stay less than 4GB total as that notebook only supports up to 4GB.